# Submitting MR job to Hadoop cluster with different ID's

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

What is the best way in which we can submit the MR job to hadoop cluster?

## Scenario:

Developers have their own id's e.g. dev-user1, dev-user2 etc.

Hadoop cluster has various id's for various components e.g hdfs user for HDFS, yarn for YARN etc.

This means dev-user1 can't read / write HDFS as it is hdfs id that has access to HDFS.

Can anyone help me understand what is the best practice in which a developer can submit a job to hadoop cluster? I don't want to share the hadoop "specific" id details to anyone.

How does it work in real life scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> best practice in which a developer can submit a job to hadoop cluster?

Depends on the job... `yarn jar` would be a used for MapReduce

> This means dev-user1 can't read / write HDFS as it is hdfs id that has access to HDFS.

Not everything  is owned by the hdfs user. You need to make `/user/dev-user1` HDFS directory owned by that user so that's where the user has a "private" space. You can still make a directory anywhere else on HDFS that multiple users write to.

And permissions are only checked if you've explicitly enabled them on HDFS...  And even if you did, then you still can put both users into the same POSIX group, or make directories globally writable by all.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html

In production grade clusters, Hadoop is secured by Kerberos credentials and ACLs are managed via Apache Ranger or Sentry, which both allow fine-grained permission management